# Makes sense? Je sais l'opinion dont des gens discutent

Tags: grammaire

Does this makes sense?

> Je sais l'opinion dont des gens discutent.

Perhaps not *dont* here. But is there any better substitute, that would make?

I used *dont* because I realize:

> Des gens discutent **à** l'opinion.

But I'm unsure. I need help!

Comment: What are you trying to say?

Comment: Je pense que je sais de quoi on parle...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Funny enough, this is a case of getting the right thing by accident.

*dont* = of which; that is, it goes with *de* and is equivalent to *duquel*, not *à* / *auquel*.

But luckily, we say *discuter **de** quelque chose*, not *à*, so *dont* works.

However, it's actually *savoir* that's a little unusual here. There aren't many things you can use as direct objects for *savoir*. One of them is *faits* (facts), but not *opinions*.

The two best options are to replace *savoir* with *connaître*, following [this frequency chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sais%20l%27opinion%2Cconnais%20l%27opinion&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&case_insensitive=true#):

> Je connais les opinions dont les gens discutent.

Or rephrase so that what you *savoir* is the "which" rather than the opinions:

> Je sais de quelles opinions les gens discutent.

Comment: Do people discuss about opinions? Or is it rather  'people who discuss have an opinion' in which case 'Je connais l'opinion des gens qui discutent' would work better.